# Adding and removing divs on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently creating a gallery and would like to add a white tint to my images when a user hovers over an image. I've managed to add the `.view-me` div on hover but I can't work out how to remove it. I've tried `.remove()` to no success - any ideas?

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.photo-block').hover(function() {
        $(this).append("<div class='view-me' id='view-me'></div>");
        $(this).find("#view-me:last").remove();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="grid">
     <div class="photo-block"></div>
     <div class="photo-block"></div>
     <div class="photo-block"></div>
     <div class="photo-block"></div>
     <div class="photo-block"></div>
 </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcPW/)

Comment: Why not use :hover in CSS to change the image opacity instead?

Comment: @PeteR I'd like to add a white tint over the image which is placed on a coloured background :).

Comment: If each image is contained in a div anyway, then set the div background-color to white, then apply the opacity to the image on hover. Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.photo-block').hover(function() {
        $('#view-me').remove();
        $(this).append("<div class='view-me' id='view-me'></div>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using css: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VW9Fq/1/)**

html:

```
<div class="photo-block">
     <div class="overlay"></div>
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400">
 </div>
```

css:

```
.photo-block {
    position: relative;
}

 .overlay {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
     display: none;
 }

 .photo-block:hover .overlay {
     display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the jQuery script to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.photo-block').hover(function () {
        $(this).append("<div class='view-me' id='view-me'></div>");
    }, function () {
        $(this).find("#view-me:last").remove();
    });
});
```

You were adding and then removing the div on the same event.
I have modified it to add the div **on hover** and remove it **on hover out**

You can check [your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcPW/3/) example as well I have modified it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/gmcPW/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.photo-block').hover(function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<div class='view-me'></div>" ) );
    }, function() {
         $( this ).find( ".view-me:last" ).remove();
    }
  );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS version as per my comment.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="photo-block">
        <img src="xyz.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid{
    background-color:#f00;
}
.photo-block{
    background-color:#fff;
}
.photo-block img:hover{
    opacity:0.4;
}
```